# Time interceptions (employee night working time) - VB.net, C#, Pseudo Code

Tags: c#, vb.net, datetime, time

I don't really have a technical question, it's more that I have been wracking my brain for hours to find a solution for a certain problem. I cannot belive that I am the first one to solve this, but google left me alone. So, may be there is someone who did this before.

This is the problem: Let's say employees who work during night time get certain surcharges on their salary. "Night time", per definition, goes from 23:00 to 06:00 (11 pm to 6 am). How can I calculate how much of a certain working period is night time. Pretty simple for the human brain, but I can't figure out the logic. Let me give you some examples:

Working time: 22:00 - 8:00 = 7 hours night time, 3 hours normal
Working time: 23:00 - 5:00 = 6 hours night time, 0 hours normal
Working time: 20:00 - 4:00 = 5 hours night time, 3 hours normal
Working time: 04:00 - 8:00 = 2 hours night time, 2 hours normal
Working time: 16:00 - 22:00 = 0 hours night time, 6 hours normal

This is my code so far (shift is the actual working time of the employee), but it does not work. It doesn't work for working times after midnight.

```
DateTime nightTimeStart = new DateTime(1, 1, 1, 23, 0, 0);
DateTime nightTimeEnd = new DateTime(1, 1, 2, 6, 0, 0);

if (shift.UntilTime < nightTimeStart || shift.FromTime > nightTimeEnd)
    return 0;
else if (shift.UntilTime <= nightTimeEnd && shift.FromTime >= nightTimeStart)
    return (decimal)(shift.UntilTime - shift.FromTime).TotalHours;
else if (shift.UntilTime > nightTimeEnd && shift.FromTime < nightTimeStart)
    return (decimal)(nightTimeEnd - nightTimeStart).TotalHours;
else if (shift.UntilTime < nightTimeEnd && shift.FromTime < nightTimeStart)
    return (decimal)(nightTimeEnd - shift.FromTime).TotalHours;
else
    return (decimal)(shift.UntilTime - nightTimeStart).TotalHours;
```

Comment: What data structure are you using to store these values?

Comment: Currently I tried to do it with C#'s datetime with the date part set to "0001-01-01". But I am open for everything that works. One could use any structure that solves the problem.

Comment: So you have these as datetimes, not represented as an integer of the hours?  All your examples are :00.  Also, isn't the 04:00  -> 6:00 example wrong?

Comment: I just corrected the 4:00 to 6:00 example, which meant to be 4:00 to 8:00. And of course the logic should work for uneven times as wll, like 21:35 to 4:40.

Comment: Is this for a practical application?  I ask because you would need to consider someone starting work at 05:30 working all the way thought to 23:30.  You might also need to consider daylight-saving time - though that can be counted by also using UTC (though with UTC, your night-shift range would differ, potentially causing issues with the overlap over midnight).

Comment: Well, ok you worked out the examples (with the exception of 04:00 -> 06:00 as Paul points out). So what, exactly, did you do? Could you represent that as a flowchart or p-code?

Comment: Actually it is not really for a practical application (so far) and we can forget about diffrent time zones, UTC time, daylight saving time, etc. Well, peterG, I tried to figure ot some code (see my post) but it doesn't work. If I would have some p-code, I could convert it to C#. I simply do not get an idea how to solve this and was hoping someone has done that before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This GitHub Repo](https://github.com/ST-Software/Utils/blob/master/src/DateTimeUtils.cs) has a good implementation that may fit your needs

You can use it like so (note the day change from 01 to 02):

```
var nightTime = new DateTimeInterval()
{
    From = new DateTime(0001, 01, 01, 20, 00, 00),
    To = new DateTime(0001, 01, 02, 6, 00, 00)
};
var shiftTime = new DateTimeInterval()
{
    From = new DateTime(0001, 01, 01, 21, 00, 00),
    To = new DateTime(0001, 01, 01, 8, 00, 00)
};

if(shiftTime.From.Value.Hour > shiftTime.To.Value.Hour)
{
    shiftTime.To = shiftTime.To.Value.AddDays(1);
}

var overlap = DateTimeUtils.GetIntervalIntersection(nightTime, shiftTime);
var duration = (overlap.To.Value - overlap.From.Value).TotalHours;
```

---

Here is a stripped down version of the code (in case the repo is ever removed):

```
public class DateTimeInterval
{
    public DateTime? From { get; set; }
    public DateTime? To { get; set; }
}

public static class DateTimeUtils
{
    public static DateTimeInterval GetIntervalIntersection(DateTimeInterval testInterval, DateTimeInterval allowedInterval)
    {
        if (testInterval.From.Value < allowedInterval.From.Value && testInterval.To.Value < allowedInterval.From.Value
            || testInterval.From.Value > allowedInterval.To.Value && testInterval.To.Value > allowedInterval.To.Value)
        {
            return new DateTimeInterval();
        }

        DateTime from = testInterval.From < allowedInterval.From
            ? allowedInterval.From.Value
            : testInterval.From.Value;

        DateTime to = testInterval.To > allowedInterval.To
            ? allowedInterval.To.Value
            : testInterval.To.Value;

        var result = new DateTimeInterval
        {
            From = from,
            To = to
        };

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you all for posting your ideas. I just comment this one, because it is the first one. Actually all ideas lead to the same result - so does mine (see above). All lacking of a solution for one situation: The working time after midnight, like from 4:00 to 8:00. While the solution with the timespan leads to zero hours, the other solutions only work, if I add one day to to the working time. And exactly that is the catch: How do I figure out when to add one day to the working day and when not. The solution should also work is someone works from 4:00 to 14:00... Tricky.

Comment: @RainerThiele Well, if the end hour is less than the start hour, add a day. Doesn't that work pretty easily? Pseudo code: `If(From.Hour < To.Hour) { To.Day = 1 } else { To.Day = 2 }`.  This is, of course, contingent on the worker not working >= 24 hours, which I think is a reasonable assumption.

Comment: Nope. Like I said, e. g. from 4:00 (a.m.) to 8:00 (a.m.). End hour is higher than start hour. But still 2 hours night time, two hours normal time (assumig night time is until 6:00).

Answer (score 1):

I would rather encode the inclusive start time and exclusive end time as `TimeSpan`s in range `[00:00:00 - 24:00:00)`.

Then the basic intersection of the two ranges

> [startA, endA), startA < endA
>   [startB, endB), startB < endB

would be

> Max(Min(endA, endB) - Max(startA, startB), TimeSpan.Zero)

The problem is when the range `[start, end)` contains midnight shift (`end < start`). In this case, it could be treated as two non overlapping ranges `[start, 24:00:00)` and `[00:00:00, end)`. Hence the intersection of the two ranges will be the sum of the intersections of one or two source ranges with one or two target ranges, leading to total 4 combination depending on the arguments.

Here is one possible implementation of the above:

```
public static class TimeUtils
{
    static readonly TimeSpan DayStart = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0);
    static readonly TimeSpan DayEnd = new TimeSpan(24, 0, 0);
    public static TimeSpan Intersect(TimeSpan startA, TimeSpan endA, TimeSpan startB, TimeSpan endB)
    {
        if (startA < endA)
        {
            if (startB < endB)
                return IntersectCore(startA, endA, startB, endB);
            else
                return IntersectCore(startA, endA, startB, DayEnd)
                    + IntersectCore(startA, endA, DayStart, endB);
        }
        else
        {
            if (startB < endB)
                return IntersectCore(startA, DayEnd, startB, endB)
                    + IntersectCore(DayStart, endA, startB, endB);
            else
                return IntersectCore(startA, DayEnd, startB, DayEnd)
                    + IntersectCore(startA, DayEnd, DayStart, endB)
                    + IntersectCore(DayStart, endA, startB, DayEnd)
                    + IntersectCore(DayStart, endA, DayStart, endB);
        }
    }
    private static TimeSpan IntersectCore(TimeSpan startA, TimeSpan endA, TimeSpan startB, TimeSpan endB)
    {
        return Max(Min(endA, endB) - Max(startA, startB), TimeSpan.Zero);
    }
    public static TimeSpan Max(TimeSpan a, TimeSpan b)
    {
        return a > b ? a : b;
    }
    public static TimeSpan Min(TimeSpan a, TimeSpan b)
    {
        return a < b ? a : b;
    }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
var nightWorkTime = TimeUtils.Intersect(
    new TimeSpan(22, 00, 00), new TimeSpan(08, 00, 00), // Working time: 22:00 - 8:00,
    new TimeSpan(23, 00, 00), new TimeSpan(06, 00, 00) // Night time: 23:00 - 6:00
);
// 07:00:00
```

Comment: It turns out that the issue is more complicated than I though initially. Hope that the updated code handles all cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can also loop over the time and check if it's within the night range

```cs
private static DateTime nightTimeStart = new DateTime(1, 1, 1, 23, 0, 0);
private static DateTime nightTimeEnd = new DateTime(1, 1, 2, 6, 0, 0);

private struct WorkHours
{
    public int NightHours;
    public int DayHours;
}

private static WorkHours GetWorkHours(DateTime t1, DateTime t2)
{
    WorkHours result = new WorkHours();
    for (DateTime i = t1; i < t2; i = i.AddHours(1))
    {
        if (i >= nightTimeStart && i < nightTimeEnd)
            result.NightHours++;
        else
            result.DayHours++;
    }
    return result;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    WorkHours result;

    result = GetWorkHours(new DateTime(1, 1, 1, 22, 0, 0), new DateTime(1, 1, 2, 8, 0, 0));
    Console.WriteLine("{0} hours night time, {1} hours normal",
        result.NightHours, result.DayHours);

    result = GetWorkHours(new DateTime(1, 1, 1, 23, 0, 0), new DateTime(1, 1, 2, 5, 0, 0));
    Console.WriteLine("{0} hours night time, {1} hours normal",
        result.NightHours, result.DayHours);

    result = GetWorkHours(new DateTime(1, 1, 1, 20, 0, 0), new DateTime(1, 1, 2, 4, 0, 0));
    Console.WriteLine("{0} hours night time, {1} hours normal",
        result.NightHours, result.DayHours);

    result = GetWorkHours(new DateTime(1, 1, 2, 4, 0, 0), new DateTime(1, 1, 2, 8, 0, 0));
    Console.WriteLine("{0} hours night time, {1} hours normal",
        result.NightHours, result.DayHours);

    result = GetWorkHours(new DateTime(1, 1, 1, 16, 0, 0), new DateTime(1, 1, 1, 22, 0, 0));
    Console.WriteLine("{0} hours night time, {1} hours normal",
        result.NightHours, result.DayHours);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

> 7 hours night time, 3 hours normal
>   
> 6 hours night time, 0 hours normal
>   
> 5 hours night time, 3 hours normal
>   
> 2 hours night time, 2 hours normal
>   
> 0 hours night time, 6 hours normal

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a solution which so far works for all my tested cases, with the working times I mentioned initially and also any night time (like 20:00-0:00, 23:00-6:00, 1:00-5:00, ...). It is based on the "DateTimeUtils" posted by MrZander.

I don't know if this is the only or the best solution. Actually I must say that the code is a bit strange, but it works. If I find a better solution later, I will re-post it. Here is what I did:

First I modified the DateTimeInterval class to make the handling easier. That should be self explaining:

```
    private class DateTimeInterval
    {
        public DateTime From { get; set; }
        public DateTime To { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan Duration
        {
            get { return (To - From); }
        }

        public DateTimeInterval() { }

        public DateTimeInterval(DateTime from, DateTime to)
        {
            From = from;
            To = to;
        }
    }
```

Then I created a list of nightTimeIntervals. That seems to be odd, but it is for the case that the night time does not cross midnight (actually in my project the night time comes from a web.config):

```
    private void SetNightTime()
    {
        DateTime nightTimeStart;
        DateTime nightTimeEnd;
        try
        {
            nightTimeStart = new DateTime(1, 1, 1, 23, 0, 0);
            nightTimeEnd = new DateTime(1, 1, 1, 6, 0, 0);

            if (nightTimeEnd < nightTimeStart)
                nightTimeEnd = nightTimeEnd.AddDays(1);

            nightTimeIntervals.Add(new DateTimeInterval(nightTimeStart, nightTimeEnd));

            if (nightTimeEnd.Date == nightTimeStart.Date)
                nightTimeIntervals.Add(new DateTimeInterval(nightTimeStart.AddDays(1), nightTimeEnd.AddDays(1)));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

To calculate the actual night working time I also created a list of time spans. I compared each nightTimeSpan with the working time and the working time plus one day (for the 4:00-8:00 in the example) and added the results to the list of timespans. From that list simply select the max value - that's it.

```
    private decimal CalculateNightWorkingHours(Shift shift)
    {
       List<TimeSpan> nightTimeSpans = new List<TimeSpan>();

        if (shift.UntilTime < shift.FromTime)
            shift.UntilTime = shift.UntilTime.AddDays(1);

        foreach (DateTimeInterval n in nightTimeIntervals)
        {
            nightTimeSpans.Add(GetIntervalIntersection(new DateTimeInterval(shift.FromTime, shift.UntilTime), n).Duration);
            nightTimeSpans.Add(GetIntervalIntersection(new DateTimeInterval(shift.FromTime.AddDays(1), shift.UntilTime.AddDays(1)), n).Duration);
        }

        return (decimal)nightTimeSpans.Max(h => h.TotalHours);
    }
```

I wouldn't be surprised if there is a better solution, but so far that's the best I could figure out.